# Apollo iOS: Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 | Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, apollo, apollo-client

I follow through [installation tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html) by [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/). And I totally confident that I did everything as is described in [installation tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html). However, when during the build of the project I received the compiler errors like:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> ```
> at Object.yargs.command.command.command.argv [as handler] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/src/cli.js:186:17)
> at Object.runCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo- codegen/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:235:44)
> at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1013:30)
> at Object.get [as argv] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:957:21)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/lib/cli.js:197:5)
> at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
> ```
>
> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

and

> ++ exec apollo-codegen generate --schema schema.json --output API.swift
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> ```
> at Object.yargs.command.command.command.argv [as handler] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/src/cli.js:186:17)
> at Object.runCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:235:44)
> at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1013:30)
> at Object.get [as argv] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:957:21)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/apollo-codegen/lib/cli.js:197:5)
> at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
> ```
>
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Why I receive this errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spending a lot of time and did searches I understood why errors appeared. Tanks to **@NiltiakSivad** for her answer on [GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/issues/34#issuecomment-380936418)

[Apollo script](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html#adding-build-step) trying to find a file with the extension **.graphql** in a project folder with appropriates **queries** or **mutations**. If they do not exist, probably you will error as above. I think that Apollo team should warn their audience about such possible case in installation tutorial!

So, in order to successfully run the project make sure:

- You're **Apollo version** compatible with **apollo-codegen**
- You correctly add [Apollo script](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html#adding-build-step)
- You have **schema.json** in the project folder
- You have file with the extension **.graphql** in a project folder that
  contains appropriates your *schema.json* **query** or **mutation**

Comment: Can you please explain how to confirm that Apollo version compatible with apollo-codegen

Comment: You should see this in the build output logs in Xcode when you will compile a project, and received the error. Don't remember how error looks like, but It will something like "you use `0.18.x` version of `apollo-codegen` but `0.16.x` is required". Also, you can find additional info here: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/issues/